# HostNetwork Flag and Non-root Container

Tags: kubernetes

I wanted to ask a question, can I use the HostNetwork flag with a non-root user pod in order to monitor the node traffic from within  a non-root container in the cluster?

I tried to achieve a non-root container to listen to the node's traffic in kubernetes